# snmp trap v3 with SHA-256

Tags: sha256, snmp4j, snmp-trap, sha2

When im using SHA , i am able to receive trap from a trap receiver test tool
(ManageEngine - OpUtils)

```
    OID authprotocolID = AuthSHA.ID;
```

When i change to SHA-256 using either one of this lines i cant receive it ( have change the configurations at my test tool). However i did see the snmp traffic via wireshark

```
     OID authprotocolID =  new OID( "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1"); //oid for sha-256
     OID authprotocolID = AuthHMAC192SHA256.ID;
```

Any idea how i can implement SHA2/SHA-256 with SNMP trap v3